# Adding bullets and decrease xaxis label interval

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, amcharts

Im working with a small app and found out that amChart is pretty nice. But I want to be able to control a couple of things and have not found out how I can do that...

First off I want the user to be able to see bullets for each datavalue, second I need to decrease the xaxis labels. I want to show all the bullets, lets say of 25 items I only want to show 1,5,10,15,20 and 25.

```
               <amq:SerialChart x:Name="foo" DataSource="{Binding Data}" CategoryValueMemberPath="axis"
                    AxisForeground="White"
                    PlotAreaBackground="Transparent"
                    GridStroke="DarkGray" 
                    LegendVisibility="Collapsed">
                    <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                        <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="value" Title="Foo" Brush="#FFFF0000" />
                    </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                </amq:SerialChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done much work on it till now, you can consider Visifire. Even msdn provides [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Charts-Gauges-in-WP7-a25c6958) for charts using their libraries.  I haven't used the amCharts but instead using the visifire charts. See the [gallery images here](http://www.visifire.com/windows_phone_charts.php). It helped me in my applications. I hope it helps you too.